# OutOfMemoryError when writing to SharedPreferences file

Tags: android, out-of-memory, sharedpreferences

I've found this curious OutOfMemoryError, I wondered if anyone else had come across it. I am breaking the rules of SharedPreferences slightly and storing a couple of model objects as strings but these are small.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.(FastXmlSerializer.java:55)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:177)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:596)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: This is weird, since there is actually no storage limit for the sharedpreferences (except string max length). Show us your implementation.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you get an OOM error-  its likely caused elsewhere in your app by using too much memory there, and you just happened to run completely out later.  Do an hprof to see where your memory is being used and check to see if you have memory leaks anywhere.

Comment: Wouldnt it be a huge coincidence that the OutOfMemoryError (assuming caused elsewhere in the app) always occurs when writing the SharedPrefs?

Comment: Are you saving large Map to SharedPreferences?

Comment: No map, although the json string is after checking closer is near to 2K. On reflection I tend to agree with the Gabe and Philipp is could be symptom not the cause of OOM.

Comment: What kind of objects are you trying to save? could you add your code where you save this objects? (and of course where you transform OO to strings

Answer (score 2):

OOM errors can happen anywhere in the App.

It's just saying: hey, I tried to allocate something but I were out of memory. Sorry.

This can happen: you load a very big image in your app and are left with very few bytes available before OOM: you then have a simple parser allocating strings and stuff.. that can go OOM.

Your problem is elsewhere :)